# Logging of errors in Angular partials

Tags: angularjs

I heard it is possible to receive the error messages of expressions, etc. in AngularJS partials. However, I can't find any information on that. Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the 
[$exceptionHandler](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24exceptionHandler)?  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj95g/1/) is a simple usage